# Best Way To Identify Groups in a Microsoft SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been banging my head against the keyboard for a good part of the day. I need help!

I have a list of clients that may or may not belong to organizations. These organizations are grouped by the type of organization. I am trying to drop reports in Excel for each group. Each group of organizations have a random number of orgs assigned to them. In the Excel sheet I need to list each organization in the group in a column and then dump a client to each row with a Y or N in the corresponding column.

My source table looks like this:

```
GROUP    ORGID    CLIENT
1        1        5
1        2        4
1        1        4
1        3        5
```

The Excel Sheet should look like this:

```
ORGNAME1     ORGNAME2     ORGNAME3      CLIENT
Y            Y            N             4
Y            N            Y             5
```

The Excel reports are generated by a C# Windows Service. I can either build the query before execution for each group or would prefer a SQL only way to execute the query that I can run as a stored procedure and just provide the organization group id.

Edit: In case I forgot to mention it...There will be one Excel document per group. Each group could contain 2-10 orgs, so it has to be dynamic.

Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL pivot see below

```
declare @orgscolumns nvarchar(max)
declare @orgs nvarchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

select @orgscolumns = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(orgname) 
            FROM orgs
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

select @orgs = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',case when ' + QUOTENAME(orgname) 
                     + ' is null then ''N'' Else ''Y'' END ' + QUOTENAME(orgname)
            FROM orgs
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')


select @query = 'select client, ' + @orgs + ' from
              ( select t.*, orgname from t inner join orgs o on t.orgid = o.id) v
              pivot ( max(orgid) for orgname in (' + @orgscolumns + ')) p'

exec(@query)
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/559f5/18)

Comment: Interesting...Does that mean you stuff the orgs into the variable delimited by commas? @orgs = (org1,org2,org3). I am going to have to read up on pivot. Never heard of it before.

Comment: yes, in `@orgscolumns` i create dynamic list of all `orgs` and `@orgs` has columns with conditions to convert value to Y, N. You can check generated sql by replacing `exec(@query)` with `print(@query)`